# How to use Spring Converter for some controllers only?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, converters

I have c converter which works:

```
public class StringToLongConverter implements Converter<String, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long convert(String source) {
        Long myDecodedValue = ...
        return myDecodedValue;
    }
}
```

In web configuration I have:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToLongConverter());
}
```

Everything is good but it works for all controllers and I need it to be executed only for some controllers.

```
//I need this controller to get myvalue from converter
@RequestMapping(value = "{myvalue}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity myvalue1(@PathVariable Long myvalue) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

//I need this controller to get myvalue without converter
@RequestMapping(value = "{myvalue}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity myvalue2(@PathVariable Long myvalue) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Can we specify which converters or parameters should be used with custom converter and which should not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally speaking, a registered `Converter` is bound to an input source and an output destination. In your case `<String, Long>`. The default Spring converter you used will apply the conversion on each matching source-destination pair.

To gain more control over when to conditionally apply the conversion, a [`ConditionalGenericConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConditionalGenericConverter.html) can be used. The interface contains 3 methods:

- `boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType)`, to determine whether the conversion should be applied
- `Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes()` to return a set of source-destination pairs the conversion can be applied to
- `Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType)` the method in which the actual conversion takes places.

I've set up a small Spring project to play around with the use of a `ConditionalGenericConverter`:

*RequiresConversion.java:*

```java
// RequiresConversion is a custom annotation solely used in this example
// to annotate an attribute as "convertable"
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresConversion {
}
```

*SomeConverter.java:*

```java
@Component
public class SomeConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        // Verify whether the annotation is present
        return targetType.getAnnotation(RequiresConversion.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(new ConvertiblePair(String.class, Long.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        // Conversion logic here
        // In this example it strips "value" from the source string
        String sourceValue = ((String) source).replace("value", "");
        return Long.valueOf(sourceValue);
    }
}
```

*SomeController.java:*

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    // The path variable used will be converted, resulting in the "value"-prefix 
    // being stripped in SomeConverter
    // Notice the custom '@RequiresConversion' annotation
    @GetMapping(value = "/test/{myvalue}")
    public ResponseEntity myvalue(@RequiresConversion @PathVariable Long myvalue) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // As the @RequiresConversion annotation is not present,
    // the conversion is not applied to the @PathVariable
    @GetMapping(value = "/test2/{myvalue}")
    public ResponseEntity myvalue2(@PathVariable Long myvalue) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The conversion will occur on http://localhost:8080/test/value123 , resulting in a `123` Long value. However, as the custom annotation `@RequiresConversion` is not present on the second mapping, the conversion on http://localhost:8080/test2/value123 will be skipped.

You could also inverse the annotation by renaming it to `SkipConversion` and verifying whether the annotation is *absent* in the `matches()` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are genius. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: A custom annotation. Nice.

Comment: If I want to convert the `String` to `List<Long>`, how should I do? Can it replace the `org.springframework.core.convert.converter` to implement arbitrary converting? Most of the example of `org.spring...converter` is about non-Generics type converting, I can't find any about converting `String` to `Optional<Long>`