# Accept and parse integer for Enum type query parameter in Java

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-boot, api

An API in my spring boot app has a query parameter of an `Enum` type.
From the postman, it accepts only `Enum` string value. It responds with 400 for integer when sent as the query parameter value.
How to configure for spring boot app to accept Enum string values or Enum index/ordinal values as query parameters.

below both the ways should work

1. `<base-url>/123/status?status=inprogress`
2. `<base-url>/123/status?status=2`
   (2 is index of inprogress `enum`)

I am using Java, spring boot fw.
It works well in dotNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this magically with an annotation or so. What you could do is implement a custom converter and convert the value inputted into your `enum` like this:

```java
public class MyCustomEnumConverter implements Converter<String, YourEnum>
{
    @Override
    public YourEnum convert(String source) {
        try
        {
            if(isNumeric(source)) // If the string passed is a Number
            {
                int index = Integer.parseInt(source); 
                return YourEnum.values()[index]; // Get the Enum at the specific index
            }
            // Else if it is a string..
            return YourEnum.valueOf(source);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null; // or whatever you need
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(str);
            return true;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then register your `Converter`:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
   @Override
   public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
       FormattingConversionService f = super.mvcConversionService();
       f.addConverter(new MyCustomEnumConverter());
       return f;
   }
}
```

You could improve the logic of `MyCustomEnumConverter` but for the sake of simplicity, I left it at that.

If you want to apply the specific `Converter` to just one controller check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539880/7954021).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reference. Will this setup auto-convert my int query param value to actual enum when it reaches the controller or Do I need to use any ConversionService to get this converted manually?

Comment: It should do this automatically. Just use the `@RequestParam` annotation and your `enum` type.

Comment: I have enabled this. It starts working but it is impacting few other places internally. I am seeing this issue at some other implementation while fetching data from repo - "Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception." Not able to figure out how this is related to the change I made. If I disable my Configuration class for Converter, I am not seeing the exception !   @Renis1235

Comment: Check this out then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536693/how-to-use-spring-converter-for-some-controllers-only . Use the Converter only on your one controller. The two error messages have nothing to do with each other though. Try it and reply if it works.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a ton @Renis1235 :)