# How to parse Thymeleaf's th:field value to java.time.Duration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, duration

I am having an issue parsing the `th:field`'s value to a variable of class `Duration`. What I want to happen is to input some numbers and I want to be saved as minutes.

This is from my `HTML` file:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{duration}">
```

On my object's side, I just initialized the variable like:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
    private Duration duration;
```

and I get an error webpage:

> Validation failed for object='bookingType'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'bookingType' on field 'duration': rejected value [15]; codes [typeMismatch.bookingType.duration,typeMismatch.duration,typeMismatch.java.time.Duration,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [bookingType.duration,duration]; arguments []; default message [duration]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration' for property 'duration'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.Duration] for value '15'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [15]]

I am using Bootstrap for the front-end, if it does matter at all.

I added the Thymeleaf's **`java8time extra`**, tried changing the input type to time and number, and I still get the same error.

Comment: *Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.Duration] for value '15';* means a `Duration` cannot be parsed from a plain numerical `String`, the unit is missing. There is a specific format that can be parsed, check the JavaDocs for it. You could possibly create fields for the supported units and concatenate them somehow.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the question is how am I supposed to parse that particular value in Thymeleaf or in the controller.

Comment: By default, `java.time.Duration` parses only text in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), with a `P` and a `T`. Your input `15` is not valid.

Comment: You can create a custom converter that will convert String -> Duration and vice versa. [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters)

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend creating `DTO`'s between your models and web interfaces, so you can move more freely.

You can see in the error and comments, the problem is clear, string input 15 is not a `Duration` and cannot be converted.

If your `Duration` value is a specific type (minute, hour ..), you can add a custom converter like this:

```java
public class StringToDurationConverter
        implements Converter<String, Duration> {

    @Override
    public Duration convert(String from) {
        return Duration.ofMinutes(
                Long.valueOf(from));
    }
}
```

We also need to tell `Spring` about this new converter by adding the `StringToDurationConverter` to the `FormatterRegistry`. This can be done by implementing the `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding `addFormatters()` method:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToDurationConverter());
    }
}
```

The default `Spring` converter we used will apply the conversion on each matching source-destination pair.

If you want to see something conditional: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539880/2039546